# Can I combine Just Blade, Incantation, and a spell?

Tags: class-feature, legend

The 'Mystic Focus' ability of Just Blade lets a character imbue their Grim Heritor with a single spell-like ability. The first circle of the Incantation track ('Incantation') is a spell-like ability, and is thus eligible. However, the *second* circle of Incantation lets a character sacrifice a spell slot and imbue their Incantation with a spell that has either a single target, an Incantation version, or both (in the last case, use the Incantation version); the spell is cast for free using the Incantation's attack roll whenever the character in question A.  uses Incantation and B. wants it to go off.

So my question is this: can I imbue my Incantation with a spell, imbue my Grim Heritor with the Incantation, and use Mystic Focus to activate both? For example: imbue my Incantation with *inflict light wounds*, imbue my Grim Heritor with my Incantation, and then attack; do I deal melee damage, then resolve the effects of my damaging Incantation, then resolve *inflict light wounds*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both discharging Mystic Focus and discharging an imbued spell are [Surge] effects, which are limited to only one per [Round].

There's also a clause on Mystic Focus to reinforce them not combining:

> "Abilities and effects other than the spell-like ability’s effects that take place as the result of a hit or critical hit don’t activate as a result of this hit."

This means that even if they weren't both [Surge] effects, the imbued spell couldn't go off from an Incantation put through Mystic Focus.

In the given example, you would inflict your melee damage, then you could only resolve your Incantation, and would not be able to cast the imbued spell. This does not result in the loss of the spell, by quirk of wording, but you still spend the action, and have activated a spell-like ability for such purposes as the Lich racial track.